# A deep understanding of the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I feel like i don't understand the Fourier transform. I've seen what it does and its properties but even after reviewing various proofs i don't understand why we end up explicitly with a relation between time and frequency.

If the transform is an extension of the series for infinite period then why cant I in principle express it as a relation between time and an approximation in time domain. 
For a series i can do that, i can write a series as as a sum of sines or cosines or exponentials involving frequency, why cant i do this with the transform.

Also would appreciate an explanation of the uncertainty principle in relation to the Fourier transform. I haven't found anything browsing.

Comment: An interesting real world application: In MRIs, we use a magnet to pull all the electrons in something in a single direction, then let go, and then the resulting signal is generated by the electric field generated by the vibrations of the atoms when we let go. The actual image that we see is a Fourier transform of that signal.

Comment: The uncertainty Principle: A Mathematical Survey by Folland and Sitaram, J. of Fourier Analysis 1997. I found this helpful. There is also a very accessible section in a book with the misleading title, "Wavelets Made Easy."